# Spectrum perturbation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint (not necessarily bounded) operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ and $B$ be self-adjoint bounded. Then how would one show that $\sigma (A+B) \subseteq \sigma(A) +\sigma(B)$? It seems that we would need a Neumann series argument, but I'm not sure of the details.

EDIT:
@Jake28 Thanks for the counterexample. In that case, my question should be that how would you prove that $\sigma(A+B) \subseteq \sigma(A) + [-||B||,||B||]$? This was the original statement, but I though it would've been possible to extend it a little.

Answer (score 1):

It might very well be that I misunderstand your question but if "self-adjoint bounded" means "self adjoint and bounded" then I think you need more assumptions on $A$ and $B$. If we consider the Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the  operators
\begin{align}A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then it's easy to check that $\sigma(A)=\{\pm1\}$ and $\sigma(B)=\{1,0\}$ whereas $\sigma(A+B)=\{\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}\}$